# GenerateAccessToken by services account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer, google-iam

I need to make a rest call to access account in google business, but I don't have an `access_token`. I just have the json of services account. My trouble is the next, how I can generate an access token starting from services account?

The call:

```
https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountName}/locations/{locationName}/reviews
```

I'm trying to generate the access token with the rest call:

```
https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/{name=projects/*/serviceAccounts/*}:generateAccessToken
```

But this returns an error:

> Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.

I understand the error, but it's not logical. It should return a short-term token without having an authentication credential, because I already have an associated service account.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding what the API `generateAccessToken` does and how to call it.

To call this API you already need an Access Token generated from User or Service Account credentials. You can use `gcloud` to create an Access Token: `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`. Then include the Access Token in the `Authorization: bearer` HTTP header.

You also need the `iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken` IAM permission on the service account that you name in the API call. This permission can be granted using `gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding` with the option `--role=roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` granting permission.

After meeting the above requirements you call this API to create a new Access Token using the specified Service Account. Basically you are using one Access Token to create another Access Token changing identities.